Given arbitrary number of triangles intersecting pairwise over hexagonal regions prove that intersection of all these triangles has positive area
Given arbitrary number of triangles intersecting pairwise over hexagonal regions prove that intersection of all these triangles has positive area. Hexagonal intersection means that every side of two intersecting triangles intersects two sides of another triangle, and all vertices of both triangles are not intersection points, as it is shown in picture below. We need to prove that blue area is positive for any number of triangles.


It is useful first to prove the following Lemma:
Let $N$ triangles intersect pairwise hexagonally. Then every line, to which any side of any intersecting triangles belongs, divides plane into two half-planes, in half-plane, where is the third vertex of triangle to which given side (one that defines line) belongs, all other triangles have exactly two vertices each, and in another half-plane all other triangles have exactly one vertex each. Moreover, If we go along the border of $N$ triangles union in one direction starting from any vertex, and mark vertices belonging to different triangles by different numbers $1, …, N$, starting with $1$, and assigning new number, higher by $1$, to each new triangle, which we did not meet so far, we will end full circle around the border of their union with following sequence of numbers:
$$1, 2, …, N, 1, 2, …, N, 1, 2, …, N$$
Proof:
Suppose that there is a line to which some side of some triangle $T_1$ in our set belongs, such that some other triangle $T_2$ in our set has two vertices $A$ and $B$ in the half-plane where triangle $T_1$ has no vertices, $T_1$ and $T_2$ cannot intersect hexagonally because side $AB$ of $T_2$ cannot participate in border of $T_1∩T_2$, which consists of exactly six intervals, belonging to sides of $T_1$ and $T_2$. Now we prove second statement of Lemma. Between first vertex on our way, which will be marked with $1$, together with other two vertices of triangle to which it belongs, and next vertex of this triangle that we already market with $1$, we will pass exactly $N-1$ vertices of $N-1$ different triangles, because all triangles in our set intersect pairwise hexagonally, and we will mark these vertices with numbers $2, …, N$. The first vertex after second $1$, that we will pass on our way, cannot be anything else but $2$, because before this vertex but after first occurrence of $2$, we already passed vertices $3, …., N, 1$. The same way we show that sequence $1, 2, … , N$ continues repeating itself exactly $3$ times before we arrive to our starting vertex $1$, as it is shown in $picture 1$ ∎

Now we start proving our main statement by induction. For $N=2$ our statement is true because any two triangles in our set intersect hexagonally, and thus their intersection has positive area. This is induction base case. Assume statement is true for some $N$. To prove our statement for $N+1$ it will suffice to show that for any line $AB$ ($A, B$ are outside of the union of $N$ triangles) that cuts union of existing set of $N$ triangles with non-zero intersection in such a way that $N$ vertices are on one side of this line and $2N$ vertices are on other side, half-plane with $N$ vertices cannot contain all intersection of existing $N$ triangles (blue area in $picture 2$). Indeed, if for any such line some part of intersection of existing $N$ triangles is on side where $2N$ vertices are, then for any new triangle $ABC$ added to existing set of $N$ triangles, which intersects with all of existing triangles hexagonally, we will have lines $AB, BC, CA$, which are cutting off the union of $N$ existing triangles exactly $N$ vertices each, in half-planes opposite to vertices $C, A, B$, correspondingly, and thus leaving some part of existing intersection inside of triangle $ABC$.  Let us prove above statement about any such line $AB$. If there is no intersection in half-plane with $N$ vertices, our statement is true, assume that there is some part of joint intersection of $N$ existing triangles in this half-plane, because only two sides of each triangle are partly present in half-plane with $N$ vertices, and because all triangles intersect pairwise hexagonally (each intersection has exactly six sides), existing triangles pairwise intersections cannot be contained completely in half-plane with $N$ vertices, as they may have only four sides there, we conclude that each of these pairwise intersections continues to the other half-plane and thus intersects over some interval with line $AB$ and thus with interval $AB$, because $A, B$ are points outside of the union of $N$ existing triangles. It follows that intervals of intersection of each of $N$ triangles with interval $AB$ are overlapping pairwise (because intersection of any pair of triangles intersects with interval $AB$ over some interval). Now, since we proved that intervals of intersection of each of $N$ triangles with interval $AB$ are overlapping pairwise, we conclude that they all overlap over some interval belonging to interval $AB$, to see this it is enough to consider interval of intersection of $AB$ with one of triangles that ends first, if we go along interval $AB$ from $A$ to $B$, and interval of intersection of $AB$ with another triangle, that starts last if we go along interval $AB$ from $A$ to $B$, because these two intervals overlap, we can call this overlap interval $X$ and conclude that intervals of intersection of interval $AB$ with all $N$ triangles must include $X$. This means that intersection of all $N$ existing triangles continues through interval $AB$ to half-plane with $2N$ vertices and by induction we proved our statement that $N$ triangles intersecting pairwise hexagonally have joint intersection with non-zero area ∎


Usually, on this site, when somebody asks a question, it means that he/she hasn't the answer or a complete answer ; it is allowed for an asker to answer his own question, some
time after. but apparently the question and the answer are synchroneous.

@Jean Marie, there is such option – to post your answer together with question, I assumed that if doing this is “not welcome” I will not be given this option. I also think that giving proof gives more chances that someone is interested in this question at all, at least it was like that in my rather small experience on this website.  I do have questions without answers and will publish them time after time, thanks for comment.

Thanks for your answer. This said, I find this question and its answers very interesting. But your question is "we need to prove..." ; I would have liked "I have found a proof that I give below. Please 1) check its validity 2) Is another proof possible ?"

Actually I would really love to see both things - validity check and alternative proofs, even "one line proof" that will make my own one look too complex, I will use your advice and next time do some remarks like that!

About an alternative solution : I am asking myself if a solution using barycentric coordinates couldn't be found... because for a triangle $ABC$, having an hexagonal intersection with any $A'B'C'$ means that on of the 3 barycentric coordinates of $A'$  (wrt $ABC$) is negative, the same for $b'$ and $C'$...

barycentric coordinates is something new to me, but from their definition it looks that they may be also useful in generalization of this statement to tetrahedrons in 3D, I was thinking of such generalization using same tools as I used here but there it looks much more  complex
